# Does the anisotropic Fermat eikonal equation predict the extraordinary ray direction given by Poynting vector?

Tags: optics, maxwell-equations, geometric-optics

Does the anisotropic Fermat eikonal equation predict the extraordinary ray direction given by Poynting vector?